# Firefox window.open not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari

I know that this problem is in many question but I haven't found a solution to my problem.

This is the original code top open a popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.open("link.php", "_blank");
</script>
```

The code works fine in all browser except Safari. To solve this I have create this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var open = window.open("link.php", "_blank");
   if (open == null || typeof(open)=='undefined')
        alert("Turn off your pop-up blocker!");
</script>
```

Now this code in firefox return me this error:

```
TypeError: window.open is not a function
var open = window.open("link.php", "_blank");
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your code a little bit like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _open = window.open("link.php", "_blank");
  if (_open == null || typeof(_open)=='undefined')
    alert("Turn off your pop-up blocker!");
  else
</script>
```

This should work now. The problem was that you're overwriting the window.open function using the global variable `open`

Comment: Wow, I don't believe it, I haven't thought that was the problem, thanks +1 for the perfect answer, as soon as possible I accept your answer. Thanks